# Mysterious pointer-related multithreading slowdown

Tags: c++, performance, multithreading, optimization, pointers

Background: So I'm working on a raytracer.. for my construction of the spatial partitioning scheme, I initially had some code like this:

```
if (msize <= 2) { // create a leaf node
    Model **models = new Model*[msize];
    for (uint i=0; i<msize; ++i)
        models[i] = &mlist[i];
    *arrayPtr = Node(models, msize); // class Node contains a copy of models
    ... increment arrayPtr ...
    return;
}
```

Basically, after this spatial partitioning tree is constructed, rays traverse the tree looking for Models, which are all stored in one big array. Leaf Nodes contain *pointers to an array of pointers* of Models.

Then I realized that hey, there's no reason for me to add that extra level of indirection; if I arrange my Models properly, I can get the leaf Nodes to point directly to the big array of models. Models adjacent to each other in the big array would all belong to a given leaf node, so the leaves would contain pointers to Models. So I did this, and tested it with everything else held constant.

Now one would think that this would obviously speed up the program. Well, it does speed up the single-threaded version (by about 10%), but it slows down the multithreaded one (by about 15%! Which is quite significant if you're doing heavy optimizing.) I'm quite at a loss on how to tackle this -- I thought indirection was bad, I thought reducing memory usage was good, *especially* for multithreading.. there's no writing whatsoever to the leaf node or the Model, all writing is done to a separate data structure.

Any pointers / suggestions on how to analyze the problem would be great.

Some miscellaneous statistics: cachegrind tells me that there are less instruction refs / cache misses for the double-indirection approach, but more data refs / cache misses. The difference isn't that large though, for both.

**Edit:** As requested, the data structure that I am concerned with:

```
class Node {
    ushort type;
    union {
        ushort axisID;
        ushort childrenSize;
    };
    union {
        Model **models;
        Node *rightChild;
    };
    float leftPlane, rightPlane;
    ... public methods and stuff ...
}
```

I basically change `Model **models` to `Model *models`, and then I get the speed dip. Class `Model` itself contains a pointer to two abstract classes, `Shape` and `Material`. All the classes mentioned here are block-allocated, with the exception of `Material` since at the moment I'm just using one.

Comment: Can you post the two versions of the data structures you are comparing?

Comment: Aliasing issues, perhaps? That's pretty much always my first thought when I see a union in C/C++. Which specific function does the profiler say becomes slower? Have you looked at the disassembly to see if any differences exist there?

Comment: How do you share the data between the threads ?

Comment: one additional experiment to try. You say you had to reorder the Models to use the pointer to Models rather than pointer to array to models. Can you test with the pointer to array to models, but with the new organization ? (ie. the pointers in the array will be consecutive).

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that you are running into [false-sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing).  If you have multiple threads both modifying memory in the same cache line, the hardware is going to spend a lot of time passing ownership of the cache line between processors.

Comment: but my Nodes and Models are both block-allocated... hmm.. how would false sharing happen in this case?

Comment: As I understand it though, neither thread modifies the data in question, which would rule out false sharing. It was my first thought too though.

Comment: What about read contention for reading the same cache-line during the same bus cycle?  I think the L1 cache is single-ported.

Answer (score 1):

Another has questioned whether the slow-down comes from the added indirection, or the change in how you allocate the `struct Model`.  Because you are now allocating the `Model` structs as a contiguous region of memory, it is possible that adjacent structs could share the same cache-line.  If your threads are simultaneously accessing adjacent structs, the will contend for access.  One read access will stall for a bus cycle whilst awaiting the other.

What is the `sizeof(class Model)`?  You might try expanding it with dummy variables until the class is the sizeof your cache line.

Another possibility is that you have changed the alignment of member variables you are accessing.  If your `sizeof(class Model)` is not a multiple of your machine's word size (e.g., 8-bytes) then an array of such objects will have some members aligned to the word size and some not.  Misalignment causes double-fetching on the memory bus, as the fetch unit reads the machine words from aligned memory locations and composites the addressed value out of those two fetches.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thing I'd look for is some improper initializtion that either makes duplicate data or has improper shared data. It's not evident in the code but it's the obvious mistake to make when going from ** to *.